# Best practice to load savegame of a management game?

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a Football Manager style management game for android phone & tablet. So I have quite a deep object model (players, teams, races, ... with all their stats, history and so on).

I want to know the best way to load a users savegame.
(in my c# desktop variant for this app I load the whole object in a static class variable so I can access it from everywhere.)

I don't know the best practice for an android app, I can't believe that loading the data from storage in the viewmodel of every individual Activity is the way to go. But I also don't know if it's a good idea to load the entire savegame in an application-object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a GlobalDataAccess class which holds your data, like you do it with c#.
The class could look like this and the mehtod is important to access youre objects in other classes:

```
// your objects and other:
private Player player;
// etc.
private static GlobalDataAccess globalInstance;
public static GlobalDataAccess Global(){
    if(globalInstance == null)
    {
         globalInstance = new GlobalDataAccess();
    }
    return globalInstance;
}
```

And if you will get some data from another class you make simply:

```
Player player = GlobalDataAccess.Global().player;
```

The only problem is to store the data...
One way is to store it about sharedpreferences, but this is little bad...
Hope i could help you in any way!

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know if it was common or a good practice to do something like this but it's a solution I'm happy with and glad you've proposed it

Comment: Im glad i could help. Thank you!